# Docker - Load balancing for docker containers

Tags: docker, load-balancing, docker-container

If I'm running multiple docker containers from a single image on a linux machine where docker is installed (only single machine, so no docker-swarm). Do I need to provide any specific load balancing configuration to docker in order to utilize all the containers?

If docker does that without any additional configuration then what load balancing policy it uses?

Comment: you could use nginx capabilities to do load balancing across your containers. I am not sure if it's possible purely with docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a reverse proxy container, like nginx, traefik, etc... Docker itself does not load balance, you can't even bind multiple containers to the same port outside swarm mode.

PS.
You can use swarm mode with only one machine (without VM), it would be a single manager node. In additional to the built-in load balancing feature, you also benefit from better abstracts (tasks, services, stacks...).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about binding the ports part. So let's say if I run two containers on two different ports and if I use docker in a swarm mode, Will docker-swarm be exposed on a seperate port, and requests coming from client will point to that port? so swarm can divert those requests to appropriate container based on the configuration?

Comment: With swarm mode, you can bind a "service" to a port. Service creates tasks(containers) that is load balanced to. So behind one port, you will have multiple containers working. This is done automatically by swarm.

Comment: Okay, this seems like a cleaner way to manage the scenarios. Thanks!